# Submit button not working in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

ideally whenever i am submitting a form php response should come back.But here my form is not getting submitted.I have seen other post related to this but nothing is helping
flow of code is taking taking input from user->ajax will drive it to the php page ->php will do data operation and and return success as output.

Following is code

## html

```
<form method="post" id="validation">


  <h3>Enter your Details:</h3>
  <div class="fields">
    <span id="message"></span>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="73">Firstname:</td>
        <td width="150">
          <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="firstname" name="firstname" required="required">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr style="margin-top::10px">
        <td>Lasttname:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="lasttname" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Street:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="Street" name="street" placeholder="street">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>City:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="city" id="city" name="city">
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>State:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="state" name="state" placeholder="state">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Mobile No:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile no">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <div id="success"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" style="margin-left:150px">


</form>
```

## Jquery

```
$("#validation").on('Submit', function(e) {
   //  $('#validation').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("gdgdsdfffffffffffffffffffffffff");
   var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
   var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
   var street = document.getElementById("street").value;
   var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
   var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
   var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
   var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "save.php",
     data: {
       firstname: fisrtname,
       lastname: lastname,
       street: street,
       city: city,
       state: state,
       mobile: mobile,
       email: email
     },

     success: function(response) {
       $("#success").html(response);
     }
   });

 });
```

## php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "mydb";
// Create connection
$conn       = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "false";
}
echo nl2br("Connected successfully\n");

//create table
$sql = "create table empdetails (id int(6) UNSIGNED                               AUTO_INCREMENT         primary key,firstname varchar(20),
               lastname varchar(20),street varchar(20),city varchar(20),state                                                 varchar(20),mobile varchar(20),email varchar(20))";
$conn->query($sql);
echo nl2br("table empdetails created successfully\n");

$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname  = $_POST["lastname"];
$street    = $_POST["street"];
$city      = $_POST["city"];
$state     = $_POST["state"];
$mobile    = $_POST["mobile"];
$email     = $_POST["email"];

$sql = "insert into empdetails(firstname,lastname,street,city,state,mobile,email) values('$firstname','$lastname','$street','$city','$state','$mobile','$email')";
//conn->query($sql);
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo nl2br("New record created successfully\n");
    echo $row = 'success';

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Do you honestly think someone will be able to read the code you have submitted? Even though I know the answer, I am reluctant to answer this.

Comment: Why did you comment out that line of JavaScript? And `firstname: fisrtname` is a typo?

Comment: @PraveenKumar : it was not that broad .. just basic mistakes.. hold can be lifted

Comment: @YoYo Too late bro... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many errors in the page .

> **1.** Your Id is Street `(capital S)`

But you are calling with small "s"

```
var street = document.getElementById("street").value;
```

Replace above by

```
var street = document.getElementById("Street").value;
```

> **2.** Your Query. appending the php variables

Your code:

```
$sql = "insert into empdetails(firstname,lastname,street,city,state,mobile,email) values('$firstname','$lastname','$street','$city','$state','$mobile','$email')";
```

Replace it with

```
$sql = "insert into empdetails(firstname,lastname,street,city,state,mobile,email) values('".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$street."','".$city."','".$state."','".$mobile."','".$email."')";
```

> **3.** Check if database credentials is proper.
>
> **4.** Check if Query is executed.

Comment: Thank you... it worked fine after making changes .

Comment: @umesh : ohh thats great man !!